# Report how much memory on stack/heap is being used by an object? (GDB)

Tags: c++, memory, gdb, stack, heap-memory

How would I determine the total amount of memory an object is using, and what percentage of that memory currently exists on the stack? What about the heap as well?
For example, given this program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(){

    //I wonder how much memory is being 
    //used on the stack/heap right now.

    std::vector<std::string> vec{"11","22","33"};

    //how about now?

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

how can I view the size of the stack and heap before and after the creation of the vector?
Is this possible to do this with GDB?
The manual provides some information on [examining memory](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory), but I haven't been able to report such information.

Comment: `sizeof vec` will be the stack size it takes since you allocated it on the stack. The free store size should be something like `vec.capacity() * sizeof(std::string)`.

Comment: For measuring heap usage, you might have a look at valgrind's massif tool:  http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Comment: Regarding heap, you may want to check out this gdb extension: https://fedorahosted.org/gdb-heap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're prepared to use GLIBC specific functions you can use [`mallinfo()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc) directly within your program to answer the question:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Using: " << mallinfo().uordblks << "\n";

    std::vector<std::string> vec{"11","22","33"};

    std::cout << "Using: " << mallinfo().uordblks << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```